# if combo box selected item is null how do I assign an empty string to it instead? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a property called ReplacementTo

and I set a value to it based on the selecteditem from the combobox, like this:

```
classEquipmentItem.ReplacementTo = cmbReplcmnt.SelectedItem.ToString
```

Now I can't use cmbReplcmnt.Text because what I actually need is the value of that SelectedItem

So problem is, if the user leaves the combobox as blank, it throws a null exception.
I decided to use the IIf function then:

```
classEquipmentItem.ReplacementTo = IIf(IsNothing(cmbReplcmnt.SelectedItem.ToString), classEquipmentItem.ReplacementTo = "", cmbReplcmnt.SelectedItem.ToString)
```

Unfortunately I still get the error

I tried using a Try-Catch for it and it worked, but I don't want to rely on the Try-Catch, so I was wondering is there a another way to work this through?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem` property.

```
IF IsNothing(cmbReplcmnt.SelectedItem) Then
    classEquipmentItem.ReplacementTo=String.Empty
Else
     classEquipmentItem.ReplacementTo=cmbReplcmnt.SelectedItem.ToString
    'OR
    'classEquipmentItem.ReplacementTo=cmbReplcmnt.SelectedValue.ToString
End If
```

Or, you can use IF or IIF

```
classEquipmentItem.ReplacementTo=IF(IsNothing(cmbReplcmnt.SelectedItem),
                     String.Empty,cmbReplcmnt.SelectedValue.ToString())
```

Comment: I tried using IIF() but I still get the null error. And if I use IF() It expects another expression

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `IsNothing(cmbReplcmnt.SelectedItem.ToString)`

The `.ToString` can't be evaluated in the case where the `SelectedItem` is `Nothing` so the `IsNothing` function fails

Your fixed code should be as follows:

```
classEquipmentItem.ReplacementTo = If(IsNothing(cmbReplcmnt.SelectedItem),  "", cmbReplcmnt.SelectedItem.ToString)
```

Even easier than that though is this:

```
classEquipmentItem.ReplacementTo = CStr(cmbReplcmnt.SelectedItem)
```